# Windows XP Pro 'Connect to' logon box greyed out with Guest

Tags: windows-xp, networking, security, windows-networking

Have a machine i've just nuked and paved to be used in a public enviroment, yet still connected to a Workgroup. Would like it to prompt for a logon when accessing any of the network shares as different departments will be using it. It does prompt for a login but the username field is greyed out.

Have disabled simple file sharing, disabled guest account, changed Local Security Policies (Network access Sharing and Security model to 'classic') all to no avail.

A google around has lots of other people with the same issues, lots of 'fixes' with very few feedback. Of course none of these work for me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is inherent of XP's authentication - it fails as the local user is unknown so automatically authenticates as Guest (inherent from Win9x / ME which used password authentication as opposed to username).

---

'Fixed' it by mapping network drives to the shares in question and specifying a user account (+password) to use for each, also removed the 'reconnect at logon' box. Added shortcuts to each on the Desktop. When a user requires one of the shares they use a shortcut and are prompted with a User Account Login screen where they can edit the username and password.